# Confirmação de fechamento do formulário

Tags: c#, winforms

Estou tentando **criar uma confirmação para quando o usuário tentar fechar um formulário** seja com um botão, ou pelo botão **`x`**, ou <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>, ou clicar com o botão direito do mouse no topo e depois clicar em fechar, etc...

Tentei usar o código abaixo mas não funcionou:

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.CloseReason == CloseReason.UserClosing)
  {
    var result = MessageBox.Show(this, "Você tem certeza que deseja sair?", "Confirmação", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);

    if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
      Application.Exit();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ao chegar no evento `FormClosing` o Form será fechado, exceto caso setarmos `true` a propriedade `Cancel` do evento.

```
    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CloseReason == CloseReason.UserClosing)
        {
            var result = MessageBox.Show(this, "Você tem certeza que deseja sair?", "Confirmação", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
            if (result != DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

---

**Nota:** caso a mensagem de confirmação não esteja sendo exibida, pode ser caso de o evento não ser disparado por não estar atachado ao form. Nesse caso confirme se o método `InitializeComponents()` dentro do arquivo *Form1.Designer.cs* contém o trecho de código:

```
this.FormClosing += new System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventHandler(this.Form1_FormClosing);
```

Comment: Não funcionou, é como se esse código não existisse, simplesmente fecha.

Comment: @Patrick Deveria funcionar, salvo se esse teu formulário não é o [principal](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7955304/352449). É o principal ?

Comment: E evento está sendo disparado? A mensagem aparece? Veja também que o teste do if é com != e não mais ==

Comment: É o formulário principal, testei com == e com !=, nenhum funcionou.

Comment: Então a mensagem de erro aparece ou nada aparece? Caso não aparece, o problema é que você simplesmente adicionou o método que deveria receber o evento, mas não atachou o evento ao form, que deveria ter esse trecho de código no método InitializeComponents() dentro do arquivo Form1.Designer.cs: `this.FormClosing += new System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventHandler(this.Form1_FormClosing);`

Comment: @iuristona Adiciona o conteúdo deste teu último comentário à tua resposta para ficar completa. ;)

Comment: @Zuul pensei nisso, mas eram 2 problemas e o segundo que chutei, não aparece na pergunta, presume-se que o evento já é atachado ao form. Já o código conforme foi perguntado de fato não funcionava, pois faltava o e.Cancel = true

Comment: @iuristona O que pensei foi adicionares do tipo: "Nota Importante: Se o problema é o facto da mensagem nem sequer aparecer, é porque XXX e deverás XXX." Assim, futuros visitantes com o mesmo problema já sabem que se aparece tem que cancelar o evento, mas se não aparece a mensagem é porque tem que anexar o evento ao formulário. (Mas claro, fica à tua consideração) :)

Comment: Esse método não serve para botões de fechamento criados pelo programador, né?

Comment: Se você está tendo problemas tente retirar esse `if (e.CloseReason == CloseReason.UserClosing)`

Answer (score 0):

Meu código está assim no Form principal:

```
        private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e){
        var result = MessageBox.Show("Deseja realmente sair?", "Rei dos Pisos", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Question);            
            if (Convert.ToString(result) == "Cancel") { e.Cancel = true; }            
    }
```

Pelo menos está funcionando quando clico no botão fechar do formulário.

Answer (score -1):

```
     var result = MessageBox.Show("Deseja realmente sair?", "Rei dos Pisos", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Question);            
            if (Convert.ToString(result) == "Cancel")
 { 
    e.Cancel = true; 
 } else{Aplication.Exit();// faltou só isso
```